# How to model a scale and its component subscales

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, spss, residuals

I am investigating the use of psychological strategies (PS) and athlete engagement (AE) in soccer players and what to predict if global / whole PS predicts AE as a whole using SPSS.

I also want to see if any of the sub-scales within PS predict any of the sub-scales within AE.

My knowledge is very limited, my data are not normally distributed but I have been told it's the residuals that matter for regressions not the data themselves?

What test do I need to use? Should I use two different tests for investigating as a whole and the separate sub-scales?